# What's the German equivalent for “noob”?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

What‘s the German equivalent of the English word *noob* as often used in computer or Internet speak?

Do note, that I’m not looking for a word that simply corresponds to *novice* or *newcomer* in everyday situations, such as *Neuling* or *Anfänger* but for a word whose use is often limited to computer and Internet speak, and is on par with the English *noob.*

Comment: I feel like there's a good backstory to this one :P

Comment: Not enough for an answer, therefore here as comment: I always found that the TV series Scrubs had a very good German localization. Specifically, Dr. Cox calling JD "newbie" was translated into German as *Flachzange*, which are literally flat pliers. I never heard it in use before but it fits just perfectly, somehow.

Comment: You can't really use *Flachzange* that anywhere else though, it's idiosyncratic.

Comment: Also, *Flachzange* does not connote new-ness at all, only stupidity and inferiority.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - neither does "noob", really. People who have played Dota for 10 years still get called noobs every day.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In German you use the same word as in English.
It’s called an [anglicism](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anglicism). *Noob* is often used in computer games:

> Du bist doch voll der Noob!

But it’s classified as a offense. *Anfänger* or *Newbie* would be more friendly.

You can also decline *noob* exactly as a German Word. For more information see also [this](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Noob) page.

Comment: It really depends on context if its offensive or not. I have seen it used in both wasy equally often.

Comment: @Polygnome IIRC, Newb was the original term for a new player and Noob was the offensive for a new player who was also an idiot in same fashion. Over time, Newb has fallen out of favour and Noob has taken both roles depending on context.

Comment: "Noob" is, in my experience, not a neutral term. The gravity of the offence certainly depends on context (=> pragmatic layer) but the general tone I still believe to be an insult.

Comment: @Devon please don't support "Denglish" ^^

Comment: @reporter this word is used in every-day german. thats a matter of fact. Language evolves; e.g. the term `download` has more german than english roots whereas `herunterladen` was added far later.

Comment: @reporter I guess Berichterstatter was already taken? Or is there some statue of limitations when using English words is not supporting "Denglish" any more? ;-)

Comment: A noob Noob tends to be a "DAU": "Dümmster Anzunehmender User"? ;-)

Comment: @alk Those two terms, while both condescending and similar, are generally used in rather different context and really don't mean the same thing (a DAU could very easily be someone who has used the software for a long term and I've never heard it in the context of games).

Comment: `Noob` would mostly be translated to `Lusche` which describes someone being bad at something. Yet, most German would use `Noob` instead because it sounds better. Also there are several other words in English which have a crappy translation to German and because of that are used in German. An example for that would be `mapping` which completely looses meaning if you translate it. @alk `DAU` is not the same as a `noob`, because DAU are considered dumb while noobs are considered very bad. Also `noobs` are mostly seen in video games and `DAU` as the user of a program like excel or such

Comment: Und im Englischen ist Noob weniger beleidigend? Wer sagt, dass Noob nicht beleidigend gemeint ist? Immer dieses Gouvernantenhafte (und ja, Gouvernante hier abwertend gemeint).

Comment: Noob is youth language, not common German

Comment: I think you could argue that a work is no longer youth language when the generation that created or adopted the word is in thier thirties; at least I think I don't anyone younger than 40 who doesn't know the meaning of noob.

Comment: @sloth There may be some noobs that do not yet know the term. ;-)

Comment: @äüö: I have seen the word "noob" being used in programming contexts too, and often enough also by people of my age (well over 50). But in that context, it is not more condescending than "newbie". I admit I am a noob at very many things too.

Answer (score 27):

With a bit of jest, some people still use *Grünschnabel* (*greenhorn*, literally “greenbeak“). It's not at all limited to internet speech, though, but if used there it has the same meaning as *noob*.

Comment: I'd say "Grünschnabel" is common and not old-fashioned outside the internet, but you wouldn't really use it in an online context.

Comment: @KWeiss I might use it in an online context. If there is any translation I would say this one. However, not many people might use it, but that doesn't mean you couldn't. Grünschnabel is just a bit out of fashion.

Comment: I might have also heard *Rotznase* used to mean the same thing.

Comment: @Mihai *Rotznase* is one way to say *brat* = naughty kid. It's not used for newbies.

Answer (score 8):

Occasionally I encounter the abbreviation

> DAU ( = Dümmster anzunehmender User)

which might be appropriate in some contexts. It is typically applied, when malfunction of a program needs to be explained as a consequence to *very* unusual, inappropriate input, or an approach was chosen, which even a moderatly informed person would not even consider.

Comment: While this may indeed be a fitting translation in some contexts, it certainly isn’t in all ones. I think you should better clarify what exactly *DAU* means and when it can be used.

Comment: This is more of an "idiot". Everybody has been a noob at the beginning, but DAUs will stay DAUs forever. ;)

Comment: DAU translates to "the stupidest user one can imagine".

Comment: Yeah DAU can be quite experienced … ;P

Comment: It is a word play on "GAU", which is a nuclear engineering abbreviation for "Größter Anzunehmender Unfall" (equivalent to DBA, design basis accident)... and it comes with all the offense potential of calling somebody dumm (stupid).

Answer (score 7):

I think, *Frischling* comes close to noob.

Originally this word means the breed of wild boar but it is also used for people who don't yet have gathered much experience in an area of work.

It basically means the same as *Neuling* but has also a slight emphasis on the fact of being more or less clueless.

Comment: You should explain the original meaning of the word and why it can be used in this case.

Comment: Frischling has the advantage of being the term for sucklings. Wouldn't have been my choice but I like it a lot.

Answer (score 5):

[*Neuling*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Neuling) is the closest native translation, which carries a connotation of lack of experience, but is less insulting.

It can also be used for experienced people who are new on the job.

I’ve witnessed this being used in several native German-speaking environments.

Comment: The question has explicitly excluded the general terms for "beginner" et al. and focused on the "netspeak" word noob specifically.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to "Noob" you can actually use *Anfänger*. In a certain context and a certain tone, it's like the English "git gud":

> Du Anfänger!

This usage is widespread in online gaming, but you can also use it when talking about other activities that require skill. This usage is most common in adolescent males.

Comment: this is the true answer

Comment: paracetamol was **not** looking for a word like _Neuling_ or _Anfänger_. In my eyes almost nobody would use a word such as _Anfänger_ or _Grünschnabel_ in online gaming.

Comment: @Devon he said "I’m not looking for a word that **simply** corresponds to novice or newcomer in everyday situations", that doesn't mean the word can't also mean that.

Answer (score 4):

Since the German language offers such a vast and colorful variety of insults (well not really, more often than not it boils down to simply adding `shit` in some kind of way to an expression), please also consider the more aggressive way of telling someone, he still has a lot to learn:

> Du Kackboon!

I find it quite interesting, that someone came up with idea of using `noob` in reverse. Nonetheless I've witnessed `Kackboon` often enough to be mentioned alongside the German use of `noob`.

Comment: Wo sage man das? Ich tippe auf den Norden. 

Comment: @alk Ich komme aus dem Süden und kenne den Begriff… ich kenne sogar jemanden, der das IRL sagt.

Comment: I've never heard that word, and I wouldn't understand it if I heard / read it.

Comment: @KWeiss I think it would be the younger generation to know such a word. I assume it got popular when it was used in SouthPark's "Make Love, not Warcraft' episode. To be fair, it is not used as much as noob.

Comment: Der Westen kennt den Begriff auch; wobei er tatsächlich nicht so weit verbreitet ist wie der gute alte noob.

Answer (score 3):

We just call them "Noob", "Amateur", "Anfänger" or "Depp". :)

But mostly "Noob" is just fine...

Comment: I find "Amateur" spot on. I'd often use "Amateur" to describe someone as a noob.

Answer (score 0):

I am astonished that nobody has provided this answer yet. I've been into online gaming for the better half of my life and can tell you with fair certainty that most German online gamers will understand the term

> Nap

(say "nup") or in spoken context

> Nappl

(say "nupil")

Example of use:

> Du bist so ein Nap!

(= "You are such a noob")

I can even provide a source for my claim: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nap (way down)

"Etymologically" it seems to come from the way the words are spoken: "noob" would be written as "nub" in German and "nub" would be pronounced like the German written word "nab", eventually arriving at the word "Nap". Seems like a long shot, but that's internet creativity in action ;)

Already mentioned synonyms that fit your question are "Boon" or the more derogatory "Kackboon" (say "cuck-boon").

Comment: never heard of that even once.

Answer (score 0):

Not a one word answer as there are already many, but with some good pop-cultural references, especciallly in music (hip hop in particular) I'd recommend `Absolute Beginner` now shortend to `Beginner` which is too broadly understood as a normal word. Otherwise as previously stated, `Noob` or `Grünschnabel` are great. The later being less internet speak though.

Answer (score 0):

A matching translation for "noob" would be "Lappen"